# How to convert NSString/NSDate to Monday 25 February

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring, nsdate

I have the following string as the `cell.textlabel.text`

**2013-02-25 00:00:00 +0000**

How can I convert it to the following format?

**Monday 25 February**

Comment: Did you even look at the spec for NSDate???  It would have led you to NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the class `NSDateFormatter` to format a date string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMMM"];

NSLog(@"Date : %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: would `new` be the string?

Comment: new is short for `[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]`

Answer (score 2):

```
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
            NSDate *arrivalDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-02-25 00:00:00 +0000"];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMMM"];
        NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:arrivalDate]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatterForDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];     
[dateFormatterForDate setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy"];
NSString *startDate = [dateFormatterForDate stringFromDate:dateString];
```

I havent checked it so try and update if it works.